# Syntax error only in IE for Arrow Notation

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've been using this line of code to match these two arrays so they have the same amount of data.

```
var items = viewModel.Date1;
var items2 = viewModel.Date2;            
items = items2.map( row =>

    //is there a matching row in items?
    items.filter( r => r.theString == row.theString).length ==  0 ?

    //if not, fill with zeros
    {theString:0, theCount:0} :

    //if there is, return the items' row
    items.filter( r => r.theString == row.theString)[0] );
```

In IE, using `=>` gives me a Syntax error.

How do I rewrite this so it works in Firefox, Chrome, and IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Arrow functions are not yet in IE.

You would be best running your code through a JS compiler like Babel, http://babeljs.io/

Comment: Thank you so much for that link. That's very handy!

Answer (score 1):

arrow function

```
r => r.theString == row.theString[0]
```

change to

```
function(r) { r.theString == row.theString[0] }
```